# Javascript dead code elimination

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'm looking for a way to reduce a javascript library/framework with the objective of only sending to the client (browser) only the necessary code. I've searched and I found that, for example, [closure compiler can't remove jquery dead code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5993048/use-closure-compiler-to-remove-unused-parts-of-jquery)

How can I write a web application, using javascript or any other languages/frameworks/tools to archive this goal? I've nothing against frameworks but in mobile devices performance counts a lot. I've tested HTML5 mobile apps on cheap android devices and it's terrible to use due to performance issues. I want to extract maximum performance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract maximum performance in terms of load times, or of speed of functionality?

Comment: Both. I want it to be as fast as possible.

Comment: Mobile(html5) has performance issues even the best libraries I know has it; there is where native and hybrid differentiates .

Comment: @Mário in that case, go native and write the functionality you need. Note this will be a slow process, but that's the tradeoff with using a framework.

Comment: Going native while targeting android, ios, etc takes time and money. I think that HTML5 have a place if done right.

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents:

In term of performance, use good practises with a linter such as jslint, jshint, or eslint.

To check wich concept is better than another one, you can check at [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/browse) or make your own ones with [benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/).

For loading time, jQuery is a bit big for mobile. [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com) is a good alternative. Imo, it's better to concat all js files on mobile than async load the js.

[MicroJs](http://microjs.com/) is a site which list all libraries that usually fit a specific need.